# How to download a source by git?

Tags: git

I would like to download a source `git://git.openscada.org/org.openscada.utgard.git` from [some website](http://openscada.org/downloads/) but there is only possibility to download it by Git.

I have downloaded a Git Bash. My question is how to download this source?

Answer (score 3):

Confirm you have Git installed on your CLI...

```
whereis git
```

You should see something like `/usr/bin/git`.

Once that's running, you can use...

```
git clone git://git.openscada.org/org.openscada.utgard.git
```

This should create a folder (`org.openscada.utgard`) with the source. If you want it to clone into a different folder, pass its name as a second argument to `git clone` as in...

`git clone git://git.openscada.org/org.openscada.utgard.git /path/to/folder`